# Передача объекта с spring контроллера на html

Tags: java, html, spring

Добрый вечер, такой вопрос. как правильно передавать объект со спринг контроллера на html вьюшку.

мой webapp

```
 @Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/frontend/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/frontend/**").addResourceLocations("/frontend/");
}
```

контроллер

```
  @RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model){
    List<User> users = userDAO.getAll();
    model.addObject("users", users);
    model.setViewName("home");
    return model;
}
```

так я на обьект ссылаюсь на вьюшке в боди:

${users}

Вместо того, чтоб отображались юзеры просто отображается надпись ${users}. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали шаблонизатор JSP, JSF, velocity и прочее). Поэтому препроцессинг перед отдачей страницы не происходит.
[Настройка thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html)

Можно и не подключать шаблонизатор, тогда включите spring el language

```
  @Bean
  public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
  }

  private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    return resolver;
  }
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста какие импорты или депенденси нужны для этих классов (а то я не могу найти).

Comment: Сходу не смогу подсказать. Среда разработки не ищет из maven репозитория?)